# why datepicker not working?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i have include jquery libray but datepicker is not working-

```
<input type="text" id="escd111" name="hsghd" readonly="readonly" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/kvch/datepicker/jsDatePick_ltr.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/kvch/datepicker/jsDatePick.min.1.3.js"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

        new JsDatePick({
            useMode:2,
            target:"escd111",
            dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
            /*selectedDate:{                This is an example of what the full configuration offers.
                day:5,                      For full documentation about these settings please see the full version of the code.
                month:9,
                year:2006
            },
            yearsRange:[1978,2020],
            limitToToday:false,
            cellColorScheme:"beige",
            dateFormat:"%m-%d-%Y",
            imgPath:"img/",
            weekStartDay:1*/
        });
    });
```

Please Help Me...........

Comment: jquery not required for this component

Answer (score 0):

In vendors example used window.onload, but you use document.ready to init you datapicker.
You need something as:

```
window.addEventListener('load',function(){
    new JsDatePick({
        useMode:2,
        target:"inputField",
        dateFormat:"%d-%M-%Y"
    });
})
```

and then all the scripts have been loaded

Answer (score 0):

**Try this Way:**

```
$("#date").datepicker({dateFormat:yyyy-mm-dd',defaultDate: "+5",showOtherMonths: true});
```